# Spring web application without redirection

Tags: spring-mvc, jdeveloper

I am trying to create a spring web application. The application should directly go to a controller and should not have any welcome file. What i am trying is

At the top of this controller I have the annotations

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and my welcome file list has root context

```
<welcome-file-list>  
        <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

So my application should run as :
localhost:7101/samplespring/

However , the problem is when I try to run the application in jdeveloper , I need to set a default target , which I obviously cannot here.

Hoow to proceed.

Thanks n Regards,
Rachit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd remove the `<welcome-file-list>` entry and ensure your `servlet-mapping` in web.xml looks something like (note `<url-pattern>`):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mainDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mainDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: The problem is jdeveloper does not launch/run the application until it finds a run configuration with a default file to launch. So I had to add an index.jsp and made it the default file that would launch when the application was launched.